# ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE when running unit tests using Chutzpah in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, visual-studio-2022, chutzpah

A recent update to Visual Studio saw the Chutzpah Unit Test Runner no longer running the tests. Using the context menu VS extension, it seems like the Kestrel web server is not initiated, hence the ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE error. Visual Studio 2022 does not work at all, but with earlier versions (2017/2019), the 'Open in browser' option works with the other context menu options failing. At least I'm not entirely blocked, it is just an annoyance to have two versions of VS installed and running specs individually rather than a range of specs in folder.

The project has very old Jasmine tests. Here is a sample of the `chutzpah.config`:

```
{
    "Engine": "Chrome",
    "TestFileTimeout": 500000
}
```

Karma is the runner and here is its config:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',

    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],

    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [ 
        'spec/*/*.spec.js',
        'spec/*/*/*.spec.js'
    ],

    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
        '../Web/Script/jquery.intellisense.js'
    ],

    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
    },

    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],

    // web server port
    port: 9876,

    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,

    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,

    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,

    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['Chrome', 'Firefox'],

    plugins: [
      'karma-chrome-launcher',
      'karma-firefox-launcher',
      'karma-ie-launcher',
      'karma-jasmine'
    ],

    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

Is there a specific config that is required for VS 2022?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the server option has defaulted to always on, disabling it solved my issue.

```
{
    ...,
    "Server": {
        "Enabled": false
    }
}
```